# mutableStateListOf change not reflecting in UI - Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

in my ViewModel:

```
private val _itemList = mutableStateListOf<Post>()
val itemList: List<Post> = _itemList

fun likePost(newPost: Post){
        val index = _itemList.indexOf(newPost)
        _itemList[index] = _itemList[index].copy(isLiked = true)
}
```

Here my Post data class:

```
data class Post(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String, 
    val isLiked: Boolean = false,
)
```

And here my Composable:

```
val postList = viewModel.itemList

LazyRow(content = {

    items(postList.size) { i ->
        val postItem = postList[i]
        PostItem(
            name = postItem.name,
            isLiked = postItem.isLiked,
            likePost = { viewModel.likePost(postItem)}
        )

    }
})
```

The change does not update in the UI instantly, I first have to scroll the updated item out of the screen so it recomposes or switch to another Screen and go back to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a `List<>` effectively and not `MutableStateList` from your ViewModel.

If you want the list to not be mutable from the view, I happen to use `MutableStateFlow<List<>>` and return `StateFlow<List<>>`. You could also just convert it to a list in your composable.

Edit:

```kotlin
//backing cached list, or could be data source like database
private val deviceList = mutableListOf<Device>()

private val _deviceListState = MutableStateFlow<List<Device>>(emptyList())
val deviceListState: StateFlow<List<BluetoothDevice>> = _deviceListState


//manipulate and publish
fun doSomething() {
    _deviceListState.value = deviceList.filter ...
}
```

In your UI

```kotlin
val deviceListState = viewModel.deviceListState.collectAsState().value
```

Comment: How can I call the likePost function with the MutableStateFlow and update one item out of the List?

        val index = _itemList.value.indexOf(newPost)
        _itemList.value[index] = _itemList.value[index].copy(isLiked = bool)

is not working.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it doesn't like updating,  it will add and delete and update instantly.  You have to do it this way when updating for our to update the state.

```
fun likePost(newPost: Post){
     val index = _itemList.indexOf(newPost)
     _itemList[index] = _itemList[index].copy()
    _itemList[index].isLiked = true
```

}